# Figure Caption Located IN Figure Array

Tags: captions, subcaption

I have a group of 7 figures (row 1 has 4 figures and row 2 has 3 figures) that I would like to put together and I would like the caption to be located in the place of the eighth figure (row 2 column 4). As shown here:

[image]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `\caption` inside a `tabular` inside your `figure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{p{.2\linewidth}} }
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}} &
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}} &
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}} &
    \caption{Here is my caption. I would like it to be located in this position.}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Some care may be required in terms of the vertical alignment of the images (labelled `B` above) with respect to the `\caption` ("raising" them into position).

Comment: I have the caption below all images and the last cell empty.

Comment: Sorry your code alone works well. Perhaps some interference with other code in my file.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro: ... do you have a question?

Comment: I have! The problem was the presence of the floatrow package in my file. Sorry again.